# Android ListView: slide-in views not shown

Tags: android, android-listview, slide

I have a ListView where each item can be slided sideways so that another view will slide in and take its place. I have implemented each list row as two views inside a horizontal RelativeLayout. One of the views are initially outside the screen.
[image]

The problem is that I am not able to make the off-screen view become rendered when it is slided into the screen, unless it is initially partly on-screen (as shown in the figure), and even this technique seems to work only when the invisible view is to the right.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I have tried to call .invalidate() and .setVisibility(VISIBLE) during slide, but to no effect.

**Update:**

**The problem** with the rendering seems to be that the Initially hidden view *always has width 0*, even if I try to change it programatically during sliding. I am using a RelativeLayout around the two views to make the visible view fit exactly into the screen.

**It is a requirement** that the views can be dragged by the finger. I currently listen to MotionEvents in a View.OnTouchListener to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague in the fact that you don't provide any code or the method by which you're sliding in/out the views. If you're not already using a View Switcher or ViewFlipper, would this not suffice?

You can also get a sliding effect using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.htm, this only allows 2 views and will slide one view in and the other view out via animations - this may be closer to what you require, but has some small drawbacks. View slider works in similar fashion to view flipper (this lets you have multiple views), below is some sample code for viewflipper.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    YOUR VIEWS

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      YOUR VIEWS

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

You can then append your own animations and call showNext on a swipe or other action to animate between the two views (in your case, a slide in and slide out animation)

```
/* Flipper animations */
yourFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in));
yourFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out));

youFlipper.showNext();
```

Simply put the view flipper in your custom cell for the listview. This handles the hiding and showing means you don't have to mess around with visible and so forth, although I appreciate you might not get exactly the same desired effect.

Comment: Thanks! 
I am currently using OnTouchListener and moving the view with the finger (drag). Would it be natural to use Switcher/Flipper also for this?

Comment: So to clarify: The dragging/sliding works fine, only that the hidden view is not shown unless it is initially partly on the screen.

Comment: It's up to you, it removes all the messy dragging and handling and will automatically scale if you use the correct layouts, but you may not get the exact desired effect. With a bit of hacking, you could probably replicate it. If you must drag it, post your code showing you're handling the offscreen view and your dragging/animating code. Also, could you maybe have it 1px on the screen but Hidden, and set it to visible on dragging? It's not an elegant solution, but you said it works if it's partially on the screen.